# How to tell all implemented interfaces and superclasses from a class in intellij?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

It seems like intellij knows the class and interface hierarchies for all of my classes, how do I get it to share that information with me?  I can navigate manually to the superclasses by clicking on whatever it lists as extending, but it's a hassle if the chain is deeper than one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Intellij Idea there is a shortcut called
**Type hierarchy** `Ctrl + H`

Example executed on the `java.io.Closable` interface, works the same way for super classes.

[image]